# How do I get my Jade plant to grow again?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, indoors, jade

We've recently moved, and while traveling to our new home all my house plants have turned brown. But importantly my jade has stopped growing. It is down to two leaves that are very loose in soil. I'm not sure what to do now. Any help?

Comment: can we have a closeup photo or two?

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing the soil and giving it some fertilizer.

Comment: It sounds like the plant is already stressed. How will disturbing its roots help it?